# tsql: select view from different database

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

Is it possible to select view defined in different database in MS SQL Server?

All my searching results point to defining view to *use data* from different database, but haven't found if it possible to select view from another database yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose you want to do a select on database DBOther than it would be :

```
select * from DBOther..TableName
```

Also check if the table or view is on the dbo schema, if not you should add the schema also : Please notice I use only one dot now after the database name

```
select * from DBOther.dbo.ViewName
```

Comment: try that on a view, which is what my OP is.

Comment: (`dbo` is not a role, it's a schema, and it [should always be specified explicitly](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx).)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the Database is in the Linked Server if they are not on the same server.

Then you can access the table or view on that database via:

```
SELECT * FROM [AnotherServerName].[DB].[dbo].[Table]
```

If on same server:

```
SELECT * FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table]
```

Comment: I did not think about when the database is on another server, good one

Comment: @GuidoG thanks, I think I'm probably overthinking about the question.